# import not found: default error when using webpack for web development

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-modules

I'm using webpack, a node.js module, in order to bundle a node.js script for use in a browser. the module did what it was meant to, but i get a strange error when in the browser from index.js. The problem seems to be with index.js, but i'm not sure:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default`.

I'll provide code below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Typing Practice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="index.js" type="module" defer></script>
        <script src="wordpicker.js" type="module" defer></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="top-container" class="top-bar">
            <h1 class="heading">Typing Practice</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="inpContainer" class="input-container">
            <div class="centeralign">
                <br><br>
                <h2 id="output" class="paragraph"></h2>
                <input type="text" id="input" class="text-field"><br>
                <button type="button" id="start" class="button">Start</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT (of the script i'm bundling)

```
const rw = require('random-words');

function getWords() {
    let words = [];

    while (words.length != 10) {
        let word = rw();
        if (word.length < 6) continue;
        else if (word.length > 10) continue;
        else words.push(word)
    }
    return words;
}

export default getWords();
```

webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/wordchecker.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'wordpicker.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'typingpractice',
    libraryTarget: 'window',
    libraryExport: 'default'
  },
};
```

import statement i'm using in index.js:
`import getWords from './wordpicker.js';`

please let me know if you can help, or if you need any more information.

Comment: `export default getWords();` should be `export default getWords;`. You want to export the function itself, not the return value of calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

in webpack.config.js, add this property

```
  target: "node",
```

also you have an error here:

```
 const rw = require('random-words');
 import rw from "random-words"
```

you cannot use require anymore

Comment: what should i use instead of require?

Comment: @PacaAT  import rw from "random-words"

Comment: but random-words is a node.js module, doesnt that mean you have to use require? i'm using import... from... in my index.js file